# Minio container for Testcontainers signature matching exception

Tags: java, integration-testing, minio, testcontainers

I have spring project with minio s3 running in docker container

When I run my app locally everything works OK, files successfully uploading and downloading.
But when Im trying to test this logic via Testcontainers on file upload request i get "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."

I run same docker container configuration in tests and outside of tests

Fun thing that i can create and list buckets, but on upload i get an exception

Here my test source code:

```
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
public class FileServiceTest {

    private static final String accessKey = "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE";
    private static final String secretKey = "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY";
    private static final Integer defaultPort = 9000;

    @Container
    private static final GenericContainer<?> minioContainer =
            new GenericContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("quay.io/minio/minio"))
                    .withExposedPorts(defaultPort)
                    .withEnv("MINIO_ACCESS_KEY", accessKey)
                    .withEnv("MINIO_SECRET_KEY", secretKey)
                    .withCommand("server", "/data");

    private final MinioClient minioClient = MinioClient.builder()
            .endpoint(minioContainer.getContainerIpAddress(), minioContainer.getMappedPort(defaultPort), false)
            .credentials(accessKey, secretKey)
            .build();
    
    @Test
    public void shouldUploadFile() throws Exception {
        String bucket = "bucket-name";
        minioClient.makeBucket(MakeBucketArgs.builder().bucket(bucket).build()); // success
        
        UUID fileId = UUID.randomUUID();
        PutObjectArgs uploadObject = PutObjectArgs.builder()
                .bucket(bucket)
                .object(fileId.toString())
                .stream(mockMultipartFile.getInputStream(), mockMultipartFile.getSize(), -1)
                .contentType(mockMultipartFile.getContentType())
                .build();
        minioClient.putObject(uploadObject); // exception here
    }
```

Any tips how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have another local instance of minio running which is returning this error. But for me, I was not able to connect to the testcontainer running minio at all, without binding the host and container ports to 9000. Therefore, I set a static host and exposed port on the container like so

```
@Container
private static final GenericContainer<?> minioContainer =
            new GenericContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse(dockerImage))
                    .withExposedPorts(exposedPort)
                    .withEnv("MINIO_ROOT_USER", accessKey)
                    .withEnv("MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD", secretKey)
                    .withCommand("server", "/data")
                    .withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd -> cmd.withHostConfig(
                            new HostConfig().withPortBindings(new PortBinding(Ports.Binding.bindPort(exposedPort), new ExposedPort(exposedPort)))));
```

This solved the problem for me